# What does Chrome use for accelerated 2D vector graphics in its HTML5 canvas draw functions?

Tags: google-chrome, opengl, 2d, chromium

So i would like to do things like what is possible with a HW accelerated HTML5 canvas for animated 2D vector graphics drawing, but on top of my OpenGL (4.x) rendered 3D scene (for complex HUD and GUI displays). I need this to be able to work on Win7+, MacOs, and Linux, mobile platform support is not needed.

BTW I am working with C++.

I was wondering if anyone knew what for example Chrome uses for accelerated 2D vector graphics in its HTML5 canvas draw functions? I was under the impression it was accelerated using ANGLE (which wraps OpenGL or DX9). Or am I wrong and its only SVG rendering that is accelerated, not the javascript canvas draw functions.

Doing HTML5 canvas style animated 2D vector graphics with OpenGL is highly non-trivial, is Google using an available library for that or is it just in-house code?

I have been looking into OpenVG and have had a hard time finding the right implementation to use for that, so far the only thing i can actually get examples compiled for is ShivaVG (but there seems to be shimmering artifacts for the tiger demo and other issues for the latest release 7 years ago). Also i think ShivaVG is using fixed function and my team decide to lock down our OpenGL usage to 4.x core profile, so that won't work. I would love to use NV_Path_Rendering but its not portable (to anything other than a nvidia accelerated device).

I also thought using OpenVG would be useful since I might be able to hide NV_Path underneath, or a new OpenVG library that might come out in the future. But I am wondering if OpenVG's future might be in peril.

Answer (score 1):

They apparently use the Skia library for all 2D rendering.